# What's the use case for a simple JOIN without "IN" in Cosmos DB SQL?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I'm trying to understand the documentation about `JOIN` in Cosmos DB SQL.

In the sample JSON, each family object has a `children` property, like this:

First family object:

```json
  "id": "AndersenFamily",
  "lastName": "Andersen",
  "children": [
     {
         "firstName": "Henriette Thaulow",
         "grade": 5
     }
  ],
```

Second family object:

```json
  "id": "WakefieldFamily",
  "children": [
     {
         "givenName": "Jesse"
     }
  ],
```

Then, this JOIN operation is shown:

```sql
SELECT f.id
    FROM Families f
    JOIN f.children
```

The obvious result is the identifier of each family object.

```json
[
  {
    "id": "AndersenFamily"
  },
  {
    "id": "WakefieldFamily"
  }
]
```

If the "JOIN" is removed, the result is exactly the same. Even I wanted to project the children, I could just use `SELECT f.id, f.children` and there would be no reason to join `f.children`.

The only difference I observe is if a family object didn't have a `children` property. Then the joining on `f.children` would exclude the family object from the results.

So what is the point of a `JOIN` in Cosmos DB SQL **without combining it with `IN`**? Is there any real use cases for it?

Comment: Your data sample only has one array element. Have you tried with multiple array elements? Effectively the join will be denormalizing, per item in the array (join is only a self-join with Cosmos DB's SQL API).

Comment: That doesn't seem to matter. Or maybe I'm not correctly understanding your comment. I have bigger sets of sample data where almost every object has multiple arrays. When using 'JOIN', these objects will be filtered out that do not have the joined array. But for the ones that do have it, there's no difference.

Comment: At this point, I would suggest editing your question to show your output, because I'm not really clear on what you're seeing, based on description alone.